# Apply function at grid cell level across layers of a raster file

Tags: r, dplyr, netcdf, terra, r-stars

I have a netcdf raster object with multiple layers (time: 30 years * 12 month = 360 steps).

The raster is constituted of multiple grid-cells (say 1000). I want to linearly detrend each month separately and each grid cell separately to obtain a residual raster object with same dimensions as the input.

For a long format data frame with columns **[x,y,value,month,year]**,  I would do it this way:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

```
data %>%
group_by(x, y, month) %>%
      nest() %>%
      mutate(model_trend = map(data,  ~ lm(value ~ year, data = .))) %>%
      mutate(augment_trend  = map(model_trend,  ~ broom::augment(.))) %>%
      unnest(cols = c(augment_trend)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      dplyr::select(x, y, year, month, .resid)
```

I am sure there are much more efficient and similarly easy ways of doing this operation using spatial packages such as `terra, stars` and so forth. Could you please advice on how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are doing as you provide no data and you do not use standard R. But here is how you can detrend cells in a SpatRaster using linear regression.

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   

n <- 1:nlyr(s)
f <- function(y) {
   residuals( lm(y ~ n) )
}
a <- app(s, f)
```

And a much faster approach with linear algebra (may not work with your data)

```
X <- cbind(1, n)
invXtX <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X)

qfun <- function(y) {
    p <- invXtX %*% y
    y - (p[1] + p[2] * n)
}

app(s, qfun) 

#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#names       :       red,      green,      blue 
#min values  : -3.833333, -17.000000, -3.833333 
#max values  :  8.500000,   7.666667,  8.500000
```

You can use the above for all months by using `tapp` instead of `app`